# Wildcard can't find the string in table sql query

Tags: sql

I'm studying SQL now.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dates 
WHERE user_id = '1891128461' 
  AND date1 = 'shop*'
```

This query can't find the data, while the following did find it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dates 
WHERE user_id = '1891128461' 
  AND date1 = 'shopmeal'
```

What is in my wildcard query is wrong?

I had followed this explanation:

`*` represents zero or more characters; `bl*` finds bl, black, blue, and blob

and `%` returns the same output (see output of variable values)

```
   command -->['/s', 'shop%']
 'date1, date2, date3' --> shop%
['date1,', 'date2,', 'date3']--> ['shop%']
items for shop% does  not exist
```

While if full word, it find (see output of variable values)

```
 /s shophardware
command -->['/s', 'shophardware']
 'date1, date2, date3' --> shophardware
['date1,', 'date2,', 'date3']--> ['shophardware']
items in a hardware  category
 - wires 2mm  sink  fan tubes 100mm
```

Comment: You don't have a [wildcard](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) query.

Comment: Do you mean date1 like 'shop%' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you say `AND date1='shop*'` in SQL is

```
AND date1 LIKE 'shop%'
```

`%` matches any string of zero or more characters, and `_` matches just one character.  To get this kind of matching, you must say `LIKE` rather than `=`.

SQL's wildcard scheme evolved separately from UNIX's glob and regular expression scheme.